# Python - Iterate Tree with Generator in Depth-First order

Tags: python, recursion, generator, yield, depth-first-search

I am trying to do a DFS on a binary tree. The tree is valid. The function itself works when the yield is replaced with a print (when it is not a generator).

```
class BinaryTree(object):
 def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root

 def dfs(self):
    print "Depth First"
    return self.depth(self.root)

 def depth(self, Node):
    print "Starts"
    yield Node
    if Node.left != None:
        print "keep it up left" 
        self.depth(Node.left)
    if Node.right != None:
        print "keep it up right"    
        self.depth(Node.right)
    print "oh no"
```

Edit: An excerpt from the main:

```
tree = BinaryTree(15) #adds the key 15 as the root
tree.addKey(10)       #adds additional entries
...
tree.addKey(5)
depthFirstSearch = tree.dfs()
for i in range(8): 
    print depthFirstSearch.next()
    print "outside of fnc"
```

For completeness, the tree looks like this:

```
{15: {10: {3: {2: , }, {5: , }}, }, {17: , {60: {23: , }, }}}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Depth First
Starts 
15
outside of fnc
keep it up left
keep it up right
oh no
```

So clearly because of the 'keep it up' debug lines, the nodes are there. It seems to skip right over the recursion step, though. Otherwise it would print Start again. I have tried replacing adding a yield to the self.depth(Node.right) statements, but that doesn't seem to help anything. Return statements are no good inside of a generator either, which makes sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind showing how you are defining `depthFirstSearch`?

Comment: My apologies, see the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `BinaryTree.depth`, you are recursing but you aren't doing anything with the recursive calls.

For example:

```
self.depth(Node.left)
```

should be something like

```
for node in self.depth(Node.left):
    yield node
```

In Python 3.3+, it can be as simple as

```
yield from self.depth(Node.left)
```

Your for loop in your "main", should look like this instead:

```
for node in depthFirstSearch:
    print node
```

I also notice that your depth first search algorithm has the right idea but you're not actually searching for anything yet. I'm guessing you already know this, though.

Comment: I know about the for loop in the main. I have been trying to learn generators and wanted to change the number of iterations so that I can play around with the StopIteration exceptions. If I am recursing, why does "Start" only print once? Your answer works like a charm.

Comment: It's the nature of generators, I assume. Lazy evaluation?

Comment: @Chet, You are correct. You can actually see that you already knew that by looking at your code. Python recognizes that any function that uses `yield` is a generator. So when a generator is called, it generates a new instance of an iterator. In your `BinaryTree.dfs` method, you are returning that generated iterator. However, in your `BinaryTree.depth` method, you are generating new iterators but you aren't doing anything with them. They are created but never used. That's why you have to yield each node in a loop. Also, in my experience, you will seldom need to explicitly use `StopIteration`.